# change mySQL default time from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column which has the data like `2012-09-09 13:20:00`, when I try to query the table, with the following query, it doesn't include the data on the to date.

```
Procedure test (IN fromdate date, IN todate date)

Select * from table where date between fromdate and todate
```

Let's say the user put in `2012-08-10` to `2012-09-09`, then it doesn't include the data on the 9th Sept. However, if I change the to date to `2012-09-10`, then it will include the data. It seems like when there is no time included, mySQL defaults to midnight or 00:00:00

Is there a way to change it or a way around this? Such as, joining the time (23:59:59) to `todate` at some stage? i.e. using the following

```
set todate = todate.STR_TO_DATE("23:59:59");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `>` and `<` operators instead of `BETWEEN` as it is not inclusive with regards to dates (assuming your column is `datetime`). If you only specify `2011-01-31`, it is the equivalent of `2011-01-31 00:00:00`.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE date > DATE_SUB(fromdate, INTERVAL 1 SECOND) 
     AND date < DATE_ADD(todate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

See it in [action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/728cf/1)

Comment: I am not sure if the syntax (todate + 1) is right, I have tried this, but it doesnt return anything.  By the way, you are right, the column is datetime, and the user input is date type.

Comment: @Will Not at all. I could have posted a better answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: I'd suggest `date >= fromdate` instead.  INTERVAL 1 SECOND might be too large a step now that MySQL 5.6 [supports DATETIME with microseconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_microsecond).

Answer (score 1):

Slow — coerce column to DATE type:

```
... WHERE DATE(column_yyyymmddhhmmss) BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
```

Faster — coerce upper boundary to DATETIME including final second of day:

```
... WHERE column_yyyymmddhhmmss BETWEEN user_fromdate AND CONCAT(user_todate, '23:59:59');
```

Comment: I believe this would prohibit the effective use of any index on that column.

Comment: @njk ach!  I misread the question, swapping columns and user-input